# How can I test if a string value is a correct xslt pattern?

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I would like to known how to test if a string value is a correct xslt pattern.

I try to use the saxon API to do this.

I wrote this :

```
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.pattern.Pattern;
import net.sf.saxon.pattern.PatternParser20;
import net.sf.saxon.sxpath.IndependentContext;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;

/**
* @param p the xslt pattern to be tested
*/
public static boolean test_Pattern2(String p) {  

        PatternParser20 pat = new PatternParser20();
        IndependentContext staticContext = new IndependentContext();        
        try {
           Pattern p = pat.parsePattern(p, staticContext);
        } catch (XPathException ex) {
            System.out.println("it is not a xslt pattern valid!");
            return false; 
        }
        catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println("NullPointerException");
        }
        System.out.println("it is a xslt pattern valid!");        
        return true;
    }
```

When my pattern is a bad xslt pattern like

> //toto and titi

I got "XPathException" and it is good but with a good xslt pattern I had a "NullPointerException". I don't understand why?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You swallow the whole exception. Add an ``e.printStackTrace()`` to the catch block of the NullPointerException and post the details.

Comment: Will this code even compile? You pass in a param `String p` and declare a `Pattern p`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a low-level interface that isn't really designed to be called externally. It will work of course if you set up everything that it needs correctly: but there's no documentation to tell you what that is, you'll only be able to work it out by debugging the failures that occur.

I would recommend instead using the s9api interface `XPathCompiler.compilePattern()` which is designed for application use and is therefore likely to be more robust.